# Windows batch file changes the location for the second command

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file

I want to create a batch file to execute my Angular project:

```
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
cd ui
npm i && npm start
```

The file simply goes to the current directory, and then goes to `ui` folder. First runs a `npm i` command, and then runs `nmp start` command. The problem is the second commands gives me the following error:

> npm ERR! path C:\Windows\System32\package.json 
>   ...

Surprisingly the locations is changed to `C:\Windows\System32\` and `npm start` command can not find a `package.json` file there.
I want to know why does it happen and how I can prevent it. I want the second command to be executed at the same directory.

Comment: Why not use `CD /D "%~dp0ui"`?

Comment: I would suggest you use `call npm i && npm start` or depending upon what you're doing next, `call npm i && call npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Compo suggested, adding a call at the beginning of the last line solved the problem.